# Installing Chrome on Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: command-line, system-installation, google-chrome, wget

I want to install Google Chrome for Linux (Ubuntu) from the terminal.
I understand the procedure to some extent.

```
wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
```

Please explain the structure if (of??) the above link after wget.

I have tried this command on my terminal,

```
wget https://www.google.com/chrome/thank-you.html?statcb=0&installdataindex=empty&defaultbrowser=0#
```

The above link after wget led to downloading setup file for Chrome in GUI Firefox, so I tried it with wget and the result is the terminal saved a file on the desktop (from where I have run the command).

The text file has:

```
--2021-01-25 18:52:13--  https://www.google.com/chrome/thank-you.html?statcb=0
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 142.250.76.164, 2404:6800:4009:81a::2004
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|142.250.76.164|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 216841 (212K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘thank-you.html?statcb=0’

thank-you.html?stat   0%[                    ]       0  --.-KB/s               
thank-you.html?stat  83%[===============>    ] 176.04K   878KB/s               
thank-you.html?stat 100%[===================>] 211.76K   972KB/s    in 0.2s    

2021-01-25 18:52:14 (972 KB/s) - ‘thank-you.html?statcb=0’ saved [216841/216841]

-- END OF TEXT FILE
```

Why is this happening? Where to get that link saying, https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb?

Comment: The cmmand ends with  `&` . You need to quote your argument: `wget 'http://...'`

Comment: but it worked well when I use the link https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb without & . can you share me what you know about wget? I am a beginner

Comment: @JayB The first wget link is the one that downloads the package file for installation.  After you run that one and it downloads the .deb file you need to install it.  It can be installed by running `sudo apt install ./google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb` from a terminal window as long as you are in the same folder you downloaded the package file to.

Comment: I think OP wants to know how to get from Download-page to the download link. But that question you should ask Google. Don't know why they don't provide a direct link. But you can use Developer Tools -> Network tab from your Browser.

Comment: @JayB Also, if you want to know about a command use `man command` from a terminal window.  So, for `wget` it would be `man wget` and it will show you that it is a non-interactive network downloader.  By the way, the second link you did from a terminal window will not do anything except for download a thank-you.html file which will do you no good.